# SSH Access via tunneling

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, ssh-tunnel

I have the following setup,

Machine A (Windows 10 & connected to ISP(X)) and Machine B (Windows 10 & connected to ISP(Y)). Both of these machines (A & B) do not have any direct connections. Machine A has access to Machine C (Linux Box running RHEL on cloud) and similarly, Machine B has access to Machine C.

Now keeping this Machine C as tunnel, is it possible to access a linux machine running in Machine B (inside VirtualBox) from Machine A? If yes how can we do this using putty? I guess this can be achieved via reverse ssh tunneling but not sure about the steps.

**Edit1:**

```
                                   PUBLIC IP        SSH (Putty) (Machine C)
Machine A Windows 10 (192.168.1.2) --> ISP(49.xxx.xxx.xxx) ---> (34.xxx.xx.xxx)

                                 PUBLIC IP          SSH (Putty)  (Machine C)
Machine B Windows 10 (192.168.1.15) --> ISP(216.xxx.xxx.xxx) --->(34.xxx.xx.xxx)

Machine B Windows 10 (192.168.1.15) --> Virtual Box (192.168.1.100)
```

Now from Machine A, I wanted to access **192.168.1.100**, how can I achieve this? There is only one machine (Machine C) where Machine A and Machine B has access to. Is there a way to do some tunneling and access **192.168.1.100** from Machine A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Machine B has a Linux virtualbox guest. I suppose you have the network of the VM configured to be on the same local network as the host, like both are on 192.168.1.x. Can you setup port forwarding from the router to the VM?

You either give too little detail about the situation, or you have an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

---

**Reverse tunnel**

Let's assume that Destination's IP is `192.168.20.55` (Linux box that you want to access).

You want to access from Linux client with IP `138.47.99.99`.

Destination (192.168.20.55) <- |NAT| <- Source (`138.47.99.99`)

1. SSH from the destination to the source (with public ip) using command below:

   ssh -R 19999:localhost:22 sourceuser@138.47.99.99

NB: port 19999 can be any unused port.

2. Now you can SSH from source to destination through SSH tuneling:

   ssh localhost -p 19999
3. 3rd party servers can also access `192.168.20.55` through Destination (`138.47.99.99`).

> Destination (192.168.20.55) <- |NAT| <- Source (138.47.99.99) <- Bob's server

4. From Bob's server:

   ssh sourceuser@138.47.99.99
5. After the sucessful login to Source:

   ssh localhost -p 19999

NB: the connection between destination and source must be alive at all time.

Tip: you may run a command (e.g. watch, top) on Destination to keep the connection active.

[Source](https://www.howtoforge.com/reverse-ssh-tunneling)

Comment: I have updated my question with some more info. Does that help you?

Comment: Do you have access to the router (internet facing) of machine B?

Comment: the problem is we don't have access to the router :|

Comment: See my updated answer